# How can I edit column width with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to change the width of the first two columns in an excel sheet but I keep getting the following error:

**wb.column_dimensions['A'].width = 25
AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'column_dimensions'**

Here's my code:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
sheet = wb.active
wb.column_dimensions['A'].width = 25
wb.column_dimensions['B'].width = 25
sheet["A1"] = "Date"
sheet["B2"] = "Name"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to address `sheet` like this:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
sheet = wb.active
sheet.column_dimensions['A'].width = 25
^
sheet.column_dimensions['B'].width = 25
^
sheet["A1"] = "Date"
sheet["B2"] = "Name"
```